# GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM error

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4.6

Recently I started getting this error everytime I commit to my local Xcode git.

fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /Volumes/xxx)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

I have partitioned my HDD into 2 drives and my source code is on one of them. All my source is local and I'm just using the built in Git with Xcode. Any clues why I get this error?

Comment: So you changed the file system after you created this git repo? And BTW the GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM bit is not the error you should worry about here.

Comment: No I created a new partition and started adding the new code there. Initially I did not get this message but it started and has been there ever since. If I move my code to the main HDD and I save to git from xcode, I dont see this message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIT\_DISCOVERY\_ACROSS\_FILESYSTEM not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853624/git-discovery-across-filesystem-not-set)

Answer (score 0):

[Check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853624/git-discovery-across-filesystem-not-set) You must be missing git init. This is the first command to start with. This command creates an empty Git repository - basically a `.git` directory