# Heroku build failing, 'fatal: Not a git repository'

Tags: node.js, git, github, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my app to Heroku but keep getting the error

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /tmp) Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).'
```

Here under the commands I type

```
$ git branch 
    -> master

$ git add -A

$ git commit -m'commit'
    ...your branch is up to date

$ git push

    everything-up-to-date

$ heroku create drumbo

    Creating ⬢ drumbo... done
    https://drumbo.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/drumbo.git

$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs

    Buildpack set. Next release on sampleapp will use heroku/nodejs.
    Run git push heroku master to create a new release using this buildpack.

$ git init (added this in because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853624/git-discovery-across-filesystem-not-set)

    Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/Berta/Desktop/Codes-senior/sampleapp/.git/

$ git push heroku master

    ...(fails with) - fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent /home/kozi) Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

$ git status 

    On branch master
    your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
    nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ ls -A 

    ... .git, .github ...
```

There's also a decent amount of verbiage about npm-merge-driver in the terminal log. Looks like the build fails right after npm install npm-merge-driver is called -

```
> drumbo@1.0.0 prepare /tmp/build_77f785ef804afd5c02fbe1c7b6f209fd
remote:        > npm-merge-driver install
remote:
remote:        fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount 
point /tmp)
remote:        Stopping at filesystem boundary 
(GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
remote:        
/tmp/build_77f785ef804afd5c02fbe1c7b6f209fd/node_modules/npm-merge- 
driver/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1100
```

However when I uninstalled the npm-merge-driver, build failed because it wasn't found.

What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things - you need to delete the prepare line from your package.json file (should be the line referring to npm-merge-driver,

and you need to make sure you add, commit, and push your code before you run npm run deploy - should clear anything up

Comment: Thanks Rick, it was that first thing you mentioned. Npm merge driver was interrupting the build. Had tried uninstalling npm-merge-driver, but also needed to take the prepare line out of the package json.