# How to repair corrupt git repository - fatal: Not a git repository?

Tags: git

I looked at many other questions to no avail.

My laptop froze during `git reset --hard` or `git checkout branch`. Not sure. After the hard reset I see

```
$ git fsck
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

I saw that `.git/index` was an empty file. Deleting it yields no results.

Any ideas how to restore? I have most my stuff pushed to a remote but I prefer to keep my branches and stashes. I have some useful stuff in there and even if I can track most of it remotely, would be hard.

Comment: May you recreate the index file? Removing that might have been a mistake.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853624/git-discovery-across-filesystem-not-set)?

Comment: @tomerpacific, I figured it out, see my answer. But there is a comment in your link that would have helped from "C. Kelly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Also my `.git/HEAD` file was empty. I've put inside it

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

Then I've run (be careful with these, in case you had uncommitted changes, you can copy your modified files safely somewhere else first).

```
git reset --hard
git clean -f
```

I found out what the issue is by running `strace git status` and noticed that it tries to find `HEAD` file in the directory path. Then it was easy.

P.S. after the fact I see that my branch where I tried to do `git reset --hard another_branch` is missing. So apparently issue happened while doing reset.

Comment: The lack of a valid `.git/HEAD` file will prevent Git from recognizing the repository as a repository, yes. There are several other conditions that will do it, such as a missing `.git/objects` directory, but the `HEAD` file is a simple file and it's relatively easy for it to be damaged by a computer crash. `git reset --hard` *should not* damage it; if it does, that generally indicates a bug in the Git code, as it's supposed to figure out that something has gone wrong and put the old `HEAD` back.

Comment: @torek, actually it could have been `checkout`. I assume `HEAD` is replaced during `checkout`. So if the crash happened while it has been truncated, then it couldn't be written to with correct data. WDYT? I will edit my answer if this sounds plausible.

Comment: Checkout typically has to overwrite `HEAD` with new contents (replacing `ref: refs/heads/br1` with `ref: refs/heads/br2` for instance). Git tends to use the "write new file, rename into place" technique (though it's not 100% consistent here). If you're allowed to delete a file, but not create a new one, that would do it, but that's a weird permission setup...